# What's the difference between graph.tx() and graph.newTransaction()?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

I'm using `GraphTraversalSource` to update vertex and edge. After user logic, I'm trying to commit my change to the server.

When I use `graph.tx().commit()` the change could be updated into the graph. But when I use `graph.newTransaction().commit()` I could not see the change in graph.

So what's the difference of these two methods to commit the change?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're asking about three different things actually:

1. `GraphTraversalSource.tx().commit()`
2. `Graph.tx().commit()`
3. `Graph.tx().createThreadedTx()` - which I believe is what you mean by `newTransaction()`

`GraphTraversalSource.tx().commit()` is just a proxy to the underlying `Graph` behind the `GraphTraversalSource` thus calling `Graph.tx().commit()`. The two can be used interchangeably, to commit the transaction bound to the current thread. Of course, it is recommended that you only interact with your graph by way of a `GraphTraversalSource` so you likely would call the `commit()` on that class. It's worth noting that unless you are in [embedded mode](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-embedded) or sending scripts to Gremlin Server that are explicitly [not transaction managed](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#considering-transactions) there is no need to ever call `commit()` as your transactions will be automatically committed for you per traversal.

As for the third item listed above `createThreadedTx()` provides a way to do [threaded transactions](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_threaded_transactions) - a link to the JanusGraph documentation for that is [here](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/tx.html#multi-thread-tx). The value of threaded transactions lies in the ability to work within the same transaction across multiple threads (the alternative is mentioned above where transactions by default are bound to the thread they are in). I imagine you referenced `newTransaction()` because it appears to be mentioned in the JanusGraph documentation. I believe that method represents the native JanusGraph API for doing multi-threaded transactions and is probably the underlying method called by TinkerPop's `createThreadedTx()`. So, if you want more portable code, you would prefer `createThreadedTx()`, though I don't believe many graph providers support this feature.

Perhaps the answer to your question about what you were seeing is apparent now, but, if not, with respect to:

> When I use graph.tx().commit() the change could be updated into the graph. But when I use graph.newTransaction().commit() I could not see the change in graph.

note that mutating the graph and then calling `g.tx().commit()` will simply commit those mutations to the graph. You made changes in the current thread and the committed them and a new transaction was automatically started in that thread.

Now, let's say you made some changes and use `graph.tx().createThreadedTx().commit()`. Well, you didn't call `commit()` on the transaction in the current thread. You created a separate multi-threaded transaction, made no mutations to the graph in it and then immediately committed it to close.